# layout with multiplie buttons to diffrent layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, button, layout

I am trying to connect with a single button on each layout to a another layout. it just work from the activity to an another layout but when i try to connect the second layout with a 3rd one it wont work. I used the **onCLick** listener method with `setContentView();` with Intent LayoutInflater. if i try to run the button with setContentView or Intent then it wont do anything and with the Layoutinflater the app will just crash. i hope you understand what i did (english is second language;) ) It will be nice if you tell me which method i need to use that i try it first by myself i don't want to show the code and you fix it for me:)

thx a lot

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_2);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_2);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: please update your code here

Comment: use intent and start activity

Comment: plz post your onclick code

Comment: @YogeshBorhade here the code

Comment: @android_jain here the code

Comment: where is 3rd button

Comment: @YogeshBorhade the 3rd one will be the same i guess my problem right know is i cant use the second button

Answer (score 0):

use below methods to switch from one intent to another

screen1 , button1
on button click use below code

```
startActivity(new Intent(screen1.this,screen2.class));
```

where screen2 is your class name of current activity and screen1 is the activity name where you want to jump

screen2 , button2
on button click use below code

```
startActivity(new Intent(screen2.this,screen1.class));
```

where screen1 is your class name of current activity and screen2 is the activity name where you want to jump

Comment: but thats with 2 activitys and do i connect the second screen to layout with onClickListener and setContentView?

Comment: you can follow above procedure and you can connect any number of activity, what exactly you want to do pz mention so that i can give clear idea about it

Comment: i try to create a app for myself that show a picture at first and i can co thru the menu bar to a nother layout with multiply button and each button will show me a layout with 2 textViews

Answer (score 0):

```
     use this on onclick change your activity name
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
```

and second activity page
  use this on onclick change your activity name

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(secondActivity.this, thirdActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thx for the answer do i need more activities or can i work just with layout and keep the code one one class?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent inte_next=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Screen.class)
            startActivity(inte_next);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent inte_next=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Screen2.class)
            startActivity(inte_next);

        }
    });

}




Screen.Java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use fragment instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.__);
```